# Really simply wordpress array issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot figure this out, when I use get_post_meta, like so

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
```

Its returns an array but printing a key such as weight like this

```
echo $meta['weight'];
```

returns another array, how am I able to use this as I simply want to print the value rather than this if I use print_r

```
Array ( [0] => 12313 )
```

I really would like to get all the values in this was as I have over 60 custom fields and do not want to have 60 lines to get each custom field individually :(

Many thanks

Comment: Use `echo $meta['weight'][0];`

Comment: echoing the key returns `array` but `print_r();` returns a single dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $meta['weight'][0];
```